# Codeigniter, Benchmark, pseudo-variables in braces '{pseudo-variables}' syntax meaning?

Tags: php, codeigniter, benchmarking

So basically the Benchmark class is very simple and it is quit clear how it works. It "remembers" the time when it was launched and when we want to know how long do the program is executing it just subtract marked time from current time.
Lets look into the code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class CI_Benchmark {

    public $marker = array();

    public function mark($name)
    {
        $this->marker[$name] = microtime(TRUE);
    }

    public function elapsed_time($point1 = '', $point2 = '', $decimals = 4)
    {
        if ($point1 === '')
        {
            return '{elapsed_time}';
        }

        if ( ! isset($this->marker[$point1]))
        {
            return '';
        }

        if ( ! isset($this->marker[$point2]))
        {
            $this->marker[$point2] = microtime(TRUE);
        }

        return number_format($this->marker[$point2] - $this->marker[$point1], $decimals);
    }

    public function memory_usage()
    {
        return '{memory_usage}';
    }

}
```

But there are still a few questions:

1. "`if ($point1 === '')`" it returns `'{elapsed_time}'`. And I kinda don't understand what it means both from syntax point of view and how do the PHP interpreter behave when it sees this line of code? What does it do in real world? Just returns the string?
2. function `memory_usage()` also not clear.
   The documentation states:

```
     * Simply returns the {memory_usage} marker.
     *
     * This permits it to be put it anywhere in a template
     * without the memory being calculated until the end.
     * The output class will swap the real value for this variable.
```

What "output class" will swap real value?

I am kinda confused, any help or explanation would be great.
:(

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28649706/8566549) explains about both pseudo-variables in CodeIgniter

Comment: "this answer explains about both pseudo-variables in CodeIgniter " - no really what I was asking...

I understand how the class works and what it should do. I read the documentation.
What I don't understand is a syntax and what if those pseudo variables returned how they will be proceeded next. If the string  '{memory_usage}' or string '{elapsed_time}' is returned what should I (my code) do with it? And how function memory_usage() can return the value itself not the pseudo variable?

Answer (score 0):

Those pseudo variables are replaced in output.php after the page is loaded in the next code:

```
        $elapsed = $BM->elapsed_time('total_execution_time_start', 'total_execution_time_end');

        if ($this->parse_exec_vars === TRUE)
        {
            $memory = round(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024, 2).'MB';
            $output = str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), $output);
        }
```

It is built like this due to the reason that we don't know how much actual memory we consumed before the page is loaded.
I will come up with more explanations in the future for "new in Codeignaiter" guys like me .